# how to set up responsive columns with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm using the following HTML markup to make 3 columns in my page:

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="sidebar-left"></div>
     <div id="content"></div>
     <div id="sidebar-right"></div>
</div>
```

These columns are styled with this CSS:

```
#container{width:100%}
#sidebar-left, .sidebar-right{width:25%;float:left}
#content{width:50%;float:left}
```

The output result is similar to the left image at <1200px width.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEopK.jpg

Now i'm trying to make a responsive design for widths less than 1200px, similar to the right image, but i can't get the content DIV on top of the sidebars. I've have tried to change the order of DIVs, but no help.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: JSfiddle please

Comment: you have idea about media queries ? which you can work on ? or you wanted to do it with plain CSS properties only ?

Comment: @venkatkrishnan yes i'm using media queries, my problem is getting the content at the top of sidebars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using flexbox would be the best thing; if you want support for lesser browsers, you could do something like this:

```css
   #content{background:green;width:100%;}
   #sidebar-right, #sidebar-left{
     background:pink;
     width:50%;float:left;
   }
   
   @media only screen and (min-width:1200px){
    #sidebar-right, #sidebar-left{ 
      width:25%;
    }
    
    #content{
      width:50%;
      margin-left:25%;
      float:left;
    }
    
    #sidebar-left{
      margin-left:-75%
    }
    
   }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    
    <div id="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer Quisque Ut Curabitur cursus sem. Integer volutpat eget tempor pulvinar Curabitur interdum Curabitur justo morbi tincidunt. Nec diam mauris adipiscing Integer Vestibulum tincidunt Suspendisse id mauris tortor. Fusce Aenean ac Lorem lorem quis tellus eu enim In id. Congue rhoncus eu Duis libero In cursus congue enim nibh laoreet. Donec nunc tellus Ut Nullam interdum dapibus malesuada turpis vitae.</p>
<p>Dui Quisque magnis interdum In ante interdum dignissim Vestibulum elit wisi. Ut Sed justo adipiscing In Vestibulum nulla et congue Nunc feugiat. Adipiscing sit id tortor ultrices vel rhoncus quis nunc nec ut. Lacus adipiscing quis tortor ornare eu Phasellus Aenean eleifend auctor pede. Porttitor tempus quam sapien adipiscing Nullam diam dolor interdum nibh adipiscing. Vestibulum dolor nibh fringilla id Vestibulum pulvinar Morbi consectetuer ut In. Malesuada sollicitudin.</p>
</div>
    <div id="sidebar-left"><p>In augue malesuada amet Phasellus ipsum orci lobortis arcu aliquam wisi. Nibh nisl lacinia Mauris neque Nam id et congue elit Integer. Mauris risus In Aliquam vitae ut est vel ut feugiat enim. Laoreet urna Vestibulum suscipit aliquam orci libero risus elit ut eget. Nibh tempus tristique tincidunt eu nibh ridiculus eleifend massa orci Aenean. Lacinia odio Vivamus.</p>
</div>

    <div id="sidebar-right"><p>Tincidunt wisi Aenean at lorem turpis gravida Curabitur neque magna sed. Orci et dictumst ligula volutpat amet mauris leo lacus ac ante. Sed fermentum ac leo nunc laoreet sociis massa platea Sed ultrices. Elit vitae tempus interdum a mollis cursus elit senectus Quisque sed. Adipiscing id semper dis sed justo congue quis tincidunt vel sit. Vitae.</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that actually works. however i'm not sure if setting that massive margin will affect the pages in the way i don't want.

Comment: umm this technique is well-established (since 2005(!)) and should not have problems - see http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use flexbox and its `order` property to achieve your desired results. Check this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yvgb440v/

Comment: Thank you, but these properties are not supported in all browser versions.

Comment: Correct, if you have to support browsers like IE9 and below flexbox is not a solution for this. But keep in mind that flexbox currently has [97% browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) globally (if you use all of its prefixed versions).

Answer (score 0):

**Method # 01:**

You can use css3 [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Following `HTML` structure can be used to create the desired layout with `flexbox`.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar-left"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="sidebar-right"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
}

#content {
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.sidebar {
  background: pink;
  padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar.left {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.sidebar.right {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  #container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  #content {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    order: -1;
  }

  .sidebar {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="sidebar left">left</div>
  <div id="content">content</div>
  <div class="sidebar right">right</div>
</div>
```

**Method # 02:**

You can use css2 table properties to create this layout. Following `HTML` structure will be required for this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="sidebar left">left</div>
    <div class="sidebar right">right</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="content-holder">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#content {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-holder,
.sidebar {
  height: 100px;
}

#content {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-holder {
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
  background: pink;
  padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar.left {
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.sidebar.right {
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  #container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #content {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
  .content-holder {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .sidebar.left,
  .sidebar.right {
    width: 48%;
  }
  .sidebar.left {
    margin-right: 2%;
  }
  .sidebar.right {
    margin-left: 2%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="sidebar left">left</div>
  <div class="sidebar right">right</div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="content-holder">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but flexbox is not supported in all browser versions.

Comment: @JackJohansson Ok, I'ev added another fallback method. you can check it.

Comment: Thank you. i assume css2 table is supported on every device and version right?

Comment: @JackJohansson almost all support this except some very old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach with CSS Flexbox and `@media` queries:

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.container {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar {
flex: 0 0 25vw;
}

.content {
flex: 0 1 50vw;
}

.left {
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.container {
background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
}

.right {
background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1200px) {

.content {
flex: 1 0 100vw;
order: 0;
}

.sidebar {
flex: 1 0 50vw;
order: 1;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="sidebar left"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="sidebar right"></div>
</div>
```